# How can integrate ShinyR function with UI?

Tags: r, shiny, bioinformatics

I am trying to develop my first small shinyR app but its UI is not going to be properly integrating with its function. When the files are browsed after running app, the function is not executed. Please find here below my code. I am new in this field and i will greatly acknowledge your support.

```
library(seqinr)
library(shiny)
# User interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Welcome to DotMatcher Plot App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (
      fileInput("protein1",
                label = "Choose a file",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept =c("text", "fasta")),
      fileInput( "protein2",
                 label = NULL,
                 multiple=FALSE,
                 accept =c("text", "fasta"))
    ),
    # Outputs
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)
)
# Server Function
server <- function(input, output) {
  movies_subset1 <- reactive({
    req(input$protein1)})
  movies_subset2 <- reactive({
    req(input$protein2)
  })
  gl<-pairwiseAlignment(pattern = movies_subset1, subject = movies_subset2)
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    print (gl)

    })

}
# App 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: where does that pairwiseAlignment function come from?

Comment: Dear I am sorry, i mistakenly pasted wrong code, please find here below the accurate version.

Comment: the code pretty much looks the same :-(

Comment: Now please find below the new code in answer section

Comment: Actually, pairwise alignment and dotmatcher codes got mixed that's why there is confusion. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of using "answers" for updated information.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use reactive expressions, you have to use brackets to get the value of that expression. I added a print statement so you can see the difference. The code should work now. But in general, since you dont manipulate your inputs, there is no need to wrap than in reactive expressions.

```
library(seqinr)
    library(shiny)
    # User interface
    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Welcome to DotMatcher Plot App"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel (
                fileInput("protein1",
                          label = "Choose a file",
                          multiple = FALSE,
                          accept =c("text", "fasta")),
                fileInput( "protein2",
                           label = NULL,
                           multiple=FALSE,
                           accept =c("text", "fasta"))
            ),
            # Outputs
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
            )
        )
    )

    # Server Function
    server <- function(input, output) {
        seq1 <- reactive({
            req(input$protein1)})
        seq2 <- reactive({
            req(input$protein2)
        })

        output$plot <- renderPlot({

    print(seq1)
    print(seq1())

            dotPlot(seq1(), seq2(), wsize = 100, wstep = 100, nmatch = 100)

        })

    }
    # App 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks dear, I am trying your code but unfortunately, when i am running my app and  uploading the sequences than getting " Error seq1 should be provided as a vector of single chars"

Comment: well since you did not provide us how the data looks I can´t make a guess here. But it looks like you have to do any kind of proprocessing of your data inside the reactive statement now

Comment: Dear can you see my preprocessing in my reactive expression. It did work for me but now i am getting Error msg at my dotPlot function

Comment: No I can not see anything. There is just your fileinput function, but I have no idea how the data looks. You should be able to solve that on your own, it has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Thanks dear, problem is fixed. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following preprocessing did work for me but now i am facing issue in my output function

```
library(seqinr)
library(shiny)
# User interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Welcome to DotMatcher Plot App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (
      fileInput("protein1",
                label = "Choose a file",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept =c("text", "fasta")),
      fileInput( "protein2",
                 label = NULL,
                 multiple=FALSE,
                 accept =c("text", "fasta"))
    ),
    # Outputs
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

# Server Function
server <- function(input, output) {
  seq1 <- reactive({
    req(s2c(paste(input$protein1, collapse = "")})
  seq2 <- reactive({
    req(s2c(paste(input$protein2, collapse = "")
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({



    dotPlot(seq1(), seq2(), wsize = 100, wstep = 100, nmatch = 100)

  })

}
# App 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```